# Error in pulling docker image from docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am not able to pull any image from docker hub. Getting the below error. ANy solution for this.

Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unable to connect to 3.215.51.67:443. Do you need an HTTP proxy?

Comment: This seems to be related: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6408

Comment: So no fix yet :( . I am facing the issue on windows 10 by the way